# How to run sh file in GIT Bash

Tags: shell, git-bash

Am trying to run physusr.sh file in GIT Bash in Windows. Am trying to set java home as below in physusr.sh file.

```
    JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
    JAVA_EXE=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java

    cd /H/US_L3/MLAdminBatchLocal/original
```

but am facing the error when I run the file GIT Bash

> ./physusr.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

> ./physusr.sh: line 1: `JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer'

I have tried using double quotes, back slash but I was getting **no such file or directory** error. How do I make this work. Should I run this sh file using any other tool.

Comment: Note: git-bash has nothing to do with Git, it's just a port of bash to Windows so that Git can *use* it. So the [tag:git] tag should be omitted. I'll snip it. Similarly, the [tag:java] tag is inappropriate as this error is just a bash syntax thing, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the '(' bracket character of '(x86)' is causing the problem. When it executes the bash file it is maybe considering it as something else but not the path. So, to solve this, tell the executor that the whole thing is a path or we can say disable the different treatment of special characters like brackets, put the path inside single quotes.
So, change it to:

```
JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer'
JAVA_EXE=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java

cd /H/US_L3/MLAdminBatchLocal/original
```

Comment: @Learner - To elaborate: shells like "bash" treat "spaces" as word delimiters, and "metacharacters" like "(" and ")" as a command grouping. SUGGESTION: Follow Spidey13's excellent advice, and use single quotes. See this link: [4.3.1. How to Avoid Shell Interpretation](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/unix_sg/shell/metachar.html) for more details.  Please "upvote" and "accept" his response if you find it helpful.